# API Gateway converting synchronous call to asyncronous

Tags: azure, asynchronous, microservices, synchronous, gateway

I have two services that must be integrated with minimum changes on both systems:

1. First system provides a way to send a command by using Azure Service Bus Queue. When the command is processed it sends an event(through Azure Service Bus Topic) about processed command back to the system that sent initial command.
2. Second service(third party) is able to make only synchronous calls, it cannot use Message Brokers by some technical limitations

Having all of this I need to integrate second service with the first and I see that it might make sense to provide API Gateway that can convert synchronous calls to asynchronous.

We use:

- Spring Boot 2.0, Spring Cloud
- Java 9
- Azure
- Azure Service Bus

I have not found any libraries or frameworks that can convert synchronous call to asynchronous. Anyway there is a way to make custom made solution:

1. API Gateway provides REST API for seconds service. When second service calls Gateway, it sends a command to Azure Service Bus Queue
2. Some sort of waiting mechanism should be implemented on Gateway side, Gateway must keep second service connection open and keep it waiting till a moment when an event from second service is received. Once it picked the event up it can build a response for the synchronous call from the 3rd party system
3. I am pretty sure we will face cases when timeout of the synchronous call is over and we have not received the event from the first service. To deal with such cases we must rollback the command processed by first services(it is some sort of compensation)

[![a diagram showing the concept][1]][1]

Do you have any recommendations about some well-known libraries or patterns that can help to implement a solution for our needs?

I also want to say that I understand that synchronous conversion asynchronous is unnatural and there are some other ways like using web-hooks or call-back urls for sending response back to the caller when a command is processed. 
Unfortunately third party service is not able to provide such API for that.

Seems like there is a link that shows and names this conversion from sync to async - https://dzone.com/articles/patterns-for-microservices-sync-vs-async. 
It is called Sync Wrapper

Comment: I am in a similar situation. Were you able to resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

What I recommend is to forget about the gateway waiting for the asynchronous task to finish. IMHO, two potentially better solutions are HTTP Polling and WebHooks.

HTTP Polling - Client continuously inquires about the status of data.
Web Hooks - Event triggered by background job and sends data to target HTTP endpoint after its job is done.

Comment: Actually, I fully agree with that. Web-hooks and polling are the best option for us - https://thenewstack.io/wonderful-world-webhooks/. But I am not sure that we can force other systems to use them. Anyway, I updated my post and added a link to the name of the pattern when we convert synchronous call to asynchronous